# Is there an AIR native extension to use GameCenter APIs for turn-based games?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm planning a turn based game using the iOS 5 GameCenter (GameKit) turn-based functions. Ideally I would program the game with AIR (I'm a Flash dev), but so far I can't seem to find any already available native extension that offers that (only basic GameCenter functions), so my questions are: Does anyone know if that already exists? And secondly how complex a task would it be to create an extension that does that? Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of etc.?

** UPDATE **

There does not seem a solution to the above from Adobe. For anyone who is interested check out the Adobe Gaming SDK. It contains a Game Center ANE which I've read contains options for multiplayer but not turn-based multiplayer, at least it's a start. Comes a bit late for me as I've already learned Obj-c!

Comment: Did you ever get a response to this? I am looking for same thing. Thanks. --update-- I found the following:
http://airextensions.net/shop/extensions/game-kit-by-vitapoly/

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to jimmyo for mentioning our GameKit ANE.  Our updated version includes support for both turn-based and real-time Game Center matches.

Phil, the task is not complex with our high-level API.  You listen to three important events, and make one call each to advance turn, assign match outcome, and end game.

This ANE also provides a low-level API to the FULL native GameKit framework if you need more advanced functionalities.  That's right, the COMPLETE native GameKit framework with all the GK classes, properties, methods, delegates, and callback functions!

You can get it at https://airextensions.net/shop/extensions/game-kit-by-vitapoly/.